# Symfony form event: ChoiceType field return null unexpectedly

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.1

I'm working on symfony form which i use select2 in field for an ajax request, i listen to the `PRE_SUBMIT` event to get the list of choices and give to the `choices` options

```
$opts = $config->getOptions();
$opts['choices'] = $listImages; //array of Image object
```

but in the `PRE_SUBMIT` event in a var_dump i get the selected value in the form, and use it in the closure, and when persisted the field have null value, so i'm doing a var_dump in `POST_SUBMIT` event the field have really null as value. And i don't see what i missed

**My FormType below:**

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('image', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => false))
        //other field
        ;

       $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, $image) use ($options) {
        $listImages = $options['em']->getRepository('AlmotivAppBundle:Image')->findBy(array(
            'id' => $image
        ));

        if (!$listImages) {
            $form->add('image')->addError(new FormError(
                'Nous n\'avons pas p trouver l\'image, veuiller choisir une autre'
            ));
        }
        //die(var_dump($listImages)); //array of Image object


        $config = $form->get('image')->getConfig();
        $opts = $config->getOptions();
        $opts['choices'] = $listImages;
        $typeName = get_class($config->getType()->getInnerType());
        $form->add('image', $typeName, $opts);
        //die(var_dump($form->get('image')->getConfig()->getData())); //return null
    };

    $builder->get('image')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $image = $event->getData();
            //die(var_dump($image)); //return 10
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $image);
        }
    );
```

And i'm using the v3.1 of the framework.
If you need more just ask.

Answer (score 1):

This seems totally valid value to be returned at that point of time.

During the `PRE_SUBMIT` you get parent form and pass it to `$formModifier`, which is OK. However, that modifier does the following, among other things:

```
$typeName = get_class($config->getType()->getInnerType());
$form->add('image', $typeName, $opts);
```

It happens that you already have a field named `image` in you form, but re-adding it completely overwrites its context (including the data). In you take a peek into `Form.php`, you'll see:

<kbd>Form.php line 873</kbd>

```
$this->children[$child->getName()] = $child;
```

That said, you cannot retrieve the data once you overlap the form field.

Why do you need to retrieve the data after you re-add the field?

Comment: to persist it in the DB, the field have a `ManyToOne ` relation so i need to pass the value of the selected option to Doctrine if didn't i'll getting an error like the value is not valid.  As i can see you can't change config of a field after construction, correct me if i'm wrong, but you can override it so i did it and know i lost the data. Now the question is How can i pass the `imagesList` to the `$options[choices]` without lost the data field?

Comment: and @JovanPerovic i don't think re-add the field is a matter cause when i pass the `$event` to the closure and doing `$event->getData();` in `POST_SUBMIT` event i got the submitted data, then i re-add the field in PRE_SUBMIT event, and the mystery thing is when doing `$event->getForm();` in POST_SUBMIT my image field have `null` value and my other field have the right value. How can i handle this?

Comment: I've got two solution to handle this 1- Is to setting the data in the form myself cause i don't understand why image always got null value. 2- Use unmapped then with the event add my image field with the submitted data in type of text (which is not the best way, i think (cause image have manytoone relation with my article entity), but is the only one i've found)

Comment: Can't answer, so the thing is to work with the `EntityType` and then use the form event, in this case `PRE_SUBMIT` and `PRE_SET_DATA`, to pass the possiblity of 'choices' to the field option.  I create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/LastKhode/a224e3ba2030d31e0af7f203ad6b0189) to share